# How can I allow only one agent in robots.txt?

Tags: html, .htaccess, adsense, robots.txt, google-crawlers

I'm currently using the following code in my robots.txt to disallow any crawlers from visiting my website. But I wanna have one exception only, which is Google AdSense's crawler.

Here's my code:

`User-agent: * Disallow: /`

Google's AdSense crawler is named "Mediapartners-Google".

How can I add it as an exception, and keep blocking every other crawler there is?

Thanks, folks!

Comment: What is "robots.exe"?

Comment: And why is this tagged "html" and ".htaccess"`?

Comment: It's "robots.txt". More about it here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/create-robots-txt

Comment: I know what a "robots.txt" file is, otherwise I would not have written an answer below. U asked the question because you write of something called "robots.exe" in the title of this question. And I wonder how that happened...

Comment: An innocent mistake when you make posts at 4 in the morning, lol.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google Disallow:

User-agent: * Disallow: /
```

Not that the separating blank line between the entries is required.

---

There is no guarantee that all bots obey those rules. Bots follow those rules on a voluntary base. So "evil" bots most likely won't care...

Comment: To clarify: `Disallow:` basically means allow everything. While `Disallow: / ` means disallow all.